# Flutter - A ValueNotifier<bool> was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, dart

I received the error of `A ValueNotifier was used after being disposed.

Step to reproduce the error:

1. I navigate to `menu.dart` from `homePage.dart`.
2. Then, I go back from `menu.dart` to `homePage.dart`.
3. I navigate again to `menu.dart`. The error happened.

Error message

```
FlutterError (A `ValueNotifier<bool>` was used after being disposed.
Once you have called `dispose()` on a ValueNotifier<bool>, it can no longer be used.)
```

clearNotifier.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
ValueNotifier<bool> cancelListen =ValueNotifier(false);
```

homePage.dart

```
import 'package:project/pages/MenuFrame.dart';

...
                  IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/image.png'),
                        iconSize: 50,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(

                                  builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier>(
                                  create: (_) => cancelListen,
                                  child: MenuFrame(
                                userId: widget.userId
                              )
                                ),
                              // MaterialPageRoute(
                              // builder: (BuildContext context) => MenuFrame(
                              //   userId: widget.userId,
                              // ),
                            ),
                          )
                          .then(
 
                              );
                        },
                      )
```

menu.dart

```
import 'package:project/class/clearNotifier.dart';

class MenuFrame extends StatefulWidget {
  const MenuFrame({Key key, this.userId}) : super(key: key);

  final String userId;
  @override
  _MenuFrame createState() => _MenuFrameState();
}


  @override
  void dispose() {
    cancelListen?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: cancelListen,
        builder: (BuildContext context, bool toClearListen,Widget child){
        ....

    });
  }
```

How can I rebuild the ValueNotifier once it has been disposed?

Comment: is the ValueNotifier inside or outside your widget class

Comment: Hi, sorry I am not quite understand. I would say it is inside widget class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you navigate from `menu.dart` back to `homePage.dart`, it calls the **dispose** function in `menu.dart` and your variable **cancelListen** was disposed. Therefore, when you navigate again to `menu.dart`, it will throw an error as you see.

**Suggestion:**

Do not pass the variable **cancelListen** like that. You should create another **ValueNotifier** variable, I would temporary call it **_cancelNotifier**. You will pass the current value to `homePage.dart`:

```
MenuFrame(
  userId: widget.userId,
  value: cancelListen.value,
)
```

...............

```
late ValueNotifier<bool> _cancelNotifier;

initState() {
  _cancelNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(widget.value);
}
```

Comment: where would this late variable be declared? inside MenuFrame?

Comment: you see it has the same level as initState? Yes, it is inside `_MenuFrameState`